# Unable to SSO login Jenkins SAML 2.0 google SSO integration

Tags: jenkins, single-sign-on, google-workspace

I have configured SSO for Jenkins via google workspace.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9002495?hl=en

This works as expected but after the session expires or when trying to login after closing the tab, it gives below error. Clicking log in just keeps redirecting to the same error page.
However, it works after clearing cookies every single time before logging in. Any idea why this is happening or a solution to login without having to clear browser cookies every single time?
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google does not support SAML SLO, so this message seems to be expected behavior (meaning that the app could expire their login session but Google will remain logged in).
What I can recommend is to change the session limit on Jenkins and I found some references about it, hope it can come in handy:

#### References:

[Jenkins login session timeout](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/best-practices/setting-session-timeout)

[Github -Jenkins session timeout configuration](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-operator/issues/189)